# Dynamic Div width - only css

Tags: html, css

I have a problem I just can't solve. First my HTML:

```html
<div style="width:1000px; overflow:hidden" class="container">
  <div class="container-items">
    <div class="item-1" style="float:left">-</div>
    <div class="item-2" style="float:left">-</div>
    ....
    <div class="item-n" style="float:left">-</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

The class 'container-items' should have a dynamic width depending on the number of items (class="item-n") in it. The items in it should not wrap.
I dont want to use javascript and I dont want to set the width of "container-items" just to 9999px or something like that.

Hope someone can help

Comment: set width:auto; may be that will work

Comment: Have you tried "white-space: nowrap"? http://codepen.io/herrfischer/pen/JELqLg.

Comment: Thanks Henning Fischer, this is working for me. I had also float:left in each item element. When I remove this it works

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block` for the "container-items".

```
<div style="width:1000px; overflow:hidden" class="container">
  <div class="container-items" style="display:inline-block">
    <div class="item-1" style="float:left">-</div>
    <div class="item-2" style="float:left">-</div>
    <div class="item-n" style="float:left">-</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this is now you have got rid of the float left, you should also comment out the space between the inner divs otherwise you will get extra spacing in your result

Comment: Correct! Here's a good link with some examples
https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Just wondering, if you keep the `float:left` for the items and just add the `display:inline-block` for the container-items... isn't that what you're looking for?